# Como subo mi pagina web hecha con tailwind?

Tags: hosting, tailwind

Soy nuevo en el desarrollo web y hace poco me introduje en Tailwind. Pude crear un proyecto y se ve todo bien, pero ahora quiero subirlo a algún hosting para ver como se ve y no se como hacerlo.
Probé subiendo las carpetas del proyecto pero me da error en todos los hostings y por lo que lei, es posible que tenga que hacer un build?.

Comment: Con [Netlify](https://app.netlify.com/) podes subir HTML, CC y JS planos, si estas usando algun framework seguro que dentro del package.json tenes un comando para generar esos 3 archivos a partir del proyecto, en React por ejemplo si usas npm es 'npm run build'. El HTML, CSS y JS se generan en una carpeta comunmente llamada 'dist', esa es la que tenes que subir a netlify.

Comment: Inicialice el proyecto con el CLI de Tailwind como lo explica la pagina, tengo NPM  pero al tratar de correr el comando 'npm run build' me tira que no existe react. No tengo ni idea de react todavia, tengo que rearmar todo el proyecto en esta libreria?

Comment: Pero estas usando algun framework o libreria? React, Solid, Angular etc? o solo es html js y css planos? si lo estas usando debes tener un package.json y por lo tanto tenes los comandos dentro de la propiedad 'scripts'

Comment: Pude solucionarlo compilando el css agregando el  "build": "tailwindcss build src/css/styles.css -o dist/styles.css" en el package.json y despues copiando los demas recursos a esa carpeta. Pero la proxima vez directamente empezare un proyecto de Tailwind usando Vite para hacer el build. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda!.

Answer (score 1):

Pude solucionarlo compilando el css agregando en el script dentro del package.json "build": "tailwindcss build src/css/styles.css -o dist/styles.css"  y despues copiando los demas recursos a esa carpeta. Pero la proxima vez directamente empezare un proyecto de Tailwind usando Vite para hacer el build.